# Trigger event from one pc to another inthru LAN on the same powerbuilder app

Tags: sockets, powerbuilder

need help please.. I'm currently developing a simple queuing system for our cashier using PB7. is there a way to trigger event from the PCs of window 1 and 2 to the server computer which displays the number being called by window 1 and 2?
(we have a 3 computer setup pc1 = caller from window 1, pc2 = caller from window 2, pc3 = facilitates number displays.)

iv'e already tried findwindow function paired with the send function but it seems to work only in 1 computer.

Some friends suggested socket programming but i cannot find examples over the internet..

Thanks for the help.

Comment: ernesto, take a look at shared objects. I don't have time to flesh out a proper response but Terry Voth has a decent explanation here.

http://www.techno-kitten.com/Changes_to_PowerBuilder/New_In_PowerBuilder_6/NewPB6_-_Shared_Objects/NewPB6_-_Example_of_Using_a_Sh/newpb6_-_example_of_using_a_sh.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a database you can insert your numbers into a table (PC1 and PC2 doing this).  Then write a method on PC3 to read the latest numbers from the table via a datawindow or datastore.  This method would have to be triggered by a timer at some set interval, say every few seconds.

If you don't use a database you can do the same thing via text files.  PC1 and PC2 would have to write their numbers into a text file and then save it in a common folder on the network.  PC3 would then, at some defined interval, look for the text file, open it, read the number, then display it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir, its what i did right now since i cannot really have much knowledge and reference on socket programming on PB. But i think its more efficient will only be executed when triggered..

Comment: If you wanted efficiency you wouldn't be using a twenty year old version of PB.